# Set NHibernate database at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Imagine, I have a website, this one offer a service. To access to this service, I need to enter login/password. I'd like depending of the login set the database to use. Example :

- login1 will use database1
- login23 will use database23

Is it possible to set at runtime the database to use with Nhibernate ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can imagine that `SessionFactory` represents a database ,and `Session` represents a database connection. The `Session` is get from the `SessionFactory` ,just like you get the database connection from database.   Given a  `Session` , you cannot change the database that it connects to.

In your case, you should create the `SessionFactory` for  both the database1 and database23 .
Get the  the `Session` from database1 's `SessionFactory` if you want to connect to database1 . Otherwise , get the `Session` from database23 's `SessionFactory`

Comment: It's access several database in the application I need. But when the user access an application, access a database depending of the setting of this user

Comment: You just get the setting of the user , if he should use database 1 , get the session from database1 's SessionFactory  to use . What is your problems actually?